# httpd virtualhost - subdomains

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I'm having some issue with setting/adding sub domains.. to my apache2(httpd)..

I have this in my httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin stitofte@homiecraft.pro
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/HomieCraft
    ServerName www.homiecraft.pro
    ServerAlias homiecraft.pro
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName stats.homiecraft.pro
   ServerAlias www.stats.homiecraft.pro
   ServerAdmin stitofte@homiecraft.pro
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/stats
</VirtualHost>
```

homiecraft.pro works just fine...

but stats.homiecraft.pro doesn't work at all.... I have made a DNS a record.. And made "stats" point to the listening address... But still it doesn't work...

Any help would be nice... I have had this setup before... But for some reason i can't get it to work this time...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally the problem is in the Dns record, check the subdomain add at dns record and check the type, which is sets CNAME and the main domain the type is A.

And check too the ip direction the subdomain

Change the serverAlias at subdomains quit the www.

Comment: When i ping stats.homiecraft.pro.. It points to the correct IP... So the DNS setup is working... But with stats.homiecraft.pro in the webbrowser does not... So it is a server side problem... with my virtualhost or something... I guess..

Comment: the ip domain homiecraft.pro is 46.253.196.160 and the ip domain stats.homiecraft.pro is 108.162.198.144 the problem is in the dns record check the type of subdomains and the value, put this paramaters here

Comment: Well now it is... I changed it to CNAME to homiecraft.pro.. And I'm using cloudflare... Well i can change it back to A... And test it again...

Comment: you need change to CNAME at subdomains stats.homiecraft.pro and the value put homiecraft.pro

Comment: Now both domains has the same ip

Comment: stats.homiecraft.pro is now CNAME and is an alias of homiecraft.pro.. But it still doesn't work... The page does not show up..

Comment: well that is weird... Now it's back at 108.162.198.144.. And i haven't done anything..

Comment: Or I know why... Well it's running through cloudflare... But still homiecraft.pro still works...

Comment: both domains is up, now you have an error 500 in your code html

Answer (score 0):

In Apache2 the Virtual Hosts must be add in ../apache2/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf File instead of main configuration file i.e ../apache2/conf/httpd.conf
then reboot the apache2 servie i.e ../apache2/bin/apa[tab] -k restart.

Now It will work fine.